# The convolution (?) of $a/ (x^2 + a^2)$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Let $a$ be a nonzero real number and 
>   $$ f(x) = \frac{1}{\pi} \frac{a}{x^2 + a^2}.$$
>   Then compute
>   $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) dx$$
>   and, for $t$ a real number,
>   $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)f(t-x) dx .$$

The former is easy.
But I don't know the later.
I'm not familiar with function analysis, so please compute it using usual calculus.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Mathematica gives
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac1\pi\cdot\frac a{x^2+a^2}\cdot\frac1\pi\cdot\frac a{(t-x)^2+a^2}\ \mathsf dx = \frac{2 a^2}{\pi  \left(4 a^3+a t^2\right)},
$$
though I don't know how you'd compute this integral by hand.

Comment: You can do this by partial fractions, exactly as in the chapter on partial fractions in your calculus book.

Comment: To demystify the title a bit: You're computing the convolution of a function $f(x)$ with itself (also known as the self-convolution of $f(x)$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Res}{Res}$
$\newcommand{\i}{\mathrm{i}}$
$\newcommand{\d}{\mathrm{d}}$

This integral is a good candidate for residue calculus.

Without loss of generality, set $a=1$ and ignore the factors of $\pi$. Then

$$\begin{split}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\d x}{(x^2+1)((x-t)^2+1)}&=2\pi\i\left(\Res_{x\to \i}+\Res_{x\to t+\i}\right)\frac{\d x}{(x^2+1)((x-t)^2+1)}\\
&=2\pi\i\left(\frac{1}{(2\i)((t-\i)^2+1)}+\frac{1}{((t+\i)^2+1)(2\i)}\right)\\
&=2\pi\Re\frac{1}{(t-\i)^2+1}\\
&=\frac{2\pi}{t}\Re\frac{1}{t-2\i}\\
&=\frac{2\pi}{t^2+4}\text{.}\\
\end{split}$$

Answer (score 7):

I mean, you can just compute this using partial fraction decomposition.

$$I=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)f(t-x)dx=\frac{a^2}{\pi^2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{x^2+a^2}\frac{1}{(t-x)^2+a^2}dx$$

We write

$$\frac{1}{x^2+a^2}\frac{1}{(t-x)^2+a^2}=\frac{Ax+B}{x^2+a^2}+\frac{Cx+D}{(t-x)^2+a^2}$$

Recombining these, our equations read

$$1=(Ax+B)(x^2-2xt+t^2+a^2)+(Cx+D)(x^2+a^2)$$
$$1=(A+C)x^3+(-2tA+B+D)x^2+(t^2A+a^2A-2tB+a^2C)x+(t^2B+a^2B+a^2D)$$

The coefficient matrix reads

$$\left(\begin{array}{c}
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
1\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
-2t & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
t^2+a^2 & -2t & a^2 & 0 \\
0 & t^2+a^2 & 0 & a^2\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
A \\
B \\
C \\
D\end{array}\right)$$

We can zero out the first column somewhat easily and get

$$\left(\begin{array}{c}
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
1\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 2t & 1 \\
0 & -2t & -t^2 & 0 \\
0 & t^2+a^2 & 0 & a^2\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
A \\
B \\
C \\
D\end{array}\right)$$
and repeating this process gives a triangular matrix of

$$\left(\begin{array}{c}
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
3\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 2t & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 3t & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & t^2+4a^2\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
A \\
B \\
C \\
D\end{array}\right)$$

Our solutions are

$$D=\frac{3}{t^2+4a^2},\;\;C=-\frac{2}{t(t^2+4a^2)},\;\;B=\frac{1}{t^2+4a^2},\;\;A=\frac{2}{t(t^2+4a^2)}$$

Let's ignore how complex the constants are for the time being. First, we compute

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{x^2+a^2}dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{(t-x)^2+a^2}dx=\frac{\pi}{a}$$

This solves our integral for $B$ and $D$, so we have

$$I=\frac{4a}{\pi(t^2+4a^2)}+\frac{2a^2}{\pi^2t(t^2+4a^2)}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\left(\frac{x}{x^2+a^2}-\frac{x-t}{(t-x)^2+a^2}\right)dx$$
$$-\frac{2a^2}{\pi^2t(t^2+4a^2)}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{t}{(t-x)^2+a^2}dx$$
$$=\frac{2a}{\pi(t^2+4a^2)}+\frac{2a^2}{\pi^2t(t^2+4a^2)}\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{(t-x)^2+a^2}{x^2+a^2}\right)\Big|_{\infty}^\infty=\frac{2a}{\pi^2(t^2+4a^2)}$$